# GRASS gis: treating certain cells as starting points in mapcalc

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I am attempting to calculate the vertical height from horizontal of every point on a slope. I want to use stream beds (the lowest points in my DEM) as my starting spot, with the horizontal plane originating from there. From there, figuring out the vertical height of different points upslope should be as simple as the expression:

tan(slope.map)*horizontal distance

My horizontal distance is simply the resolution of my DEM and the slope map that was derived from it (10m).

However, I need to make sure that r.mapcalc knows that I want to use the stream beds as the origin points from which height is to be measured in that expression. I have already created a stream map using r.streams, and was now hoping someone could help me figure out how to tell r.mapcalc to use that map as the origin in figuring out vertical heights.

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear to me what you are asking. You mention a horizontal plane, and stream beds. But stream beds are not horizontal. If there's some "base" elevation and you need the difference in elevation of all pixels from that base, then it's a simple r.mapcalc expression...

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, and sorry for not being clear. 

Your way of saying it is much better. Yes, I want to use the elevation of the stream beds as the base elevation, and I would like to figure out the vertical height (or difference in elevation) of each pixel from that base elevation.

Comment: So if you just subtract the base elevation from your elevation map, you will get the difference in elevation for all pixels.

Comment: Unfortunately my situation is more complex than that, since the "base elevation" that I want to use is not static. I want to use the elevation of the streams as the base elevation, and the elevation of the streams changes at different points on the map.

My goal is to acquire the vertical height above the stream beds for any point upslope from those streams. This is where: **tan(slope.map)*horizontal distance** comes from. Unfortunately this equation only provides vertical height above the nearest downslope cell. Instead I want the vertical height above the streams. Does that make sense?

Comment: So what I'm looking for is some way to use that equation (**tan(slope.map)*horizontal distance**), but with the "starting point" being the streams, rather the nearest downslope cell from each other cell in the slope map.

Comment: Since the streams are **lines** (not points) what will be the "starting point" for any pixel up on the slope? How do you want to choose the point along the stream as the base elev for each upslope pixel ? For example, If I go to a mountain peak, on the watershed divide, from where along the stream bed do you want to measure difference in elevation?

Comment: Perhaps I'm looking at this the wrong way and instead I need to replace the 'horizontal distance" in my equation such that instead of using the resolution of my map (10m, which gives me the distance of each cell from its nearest downslope one) I should be using some measure of distance of each upslope cell from the nearest stream. Is there a way to create such a map? A 'distance map' so to speak that will provide a distance value for each cell from the nearest stream?